# Как добавить аудио эффект на сайт

Tags: javascript, html, css, аудио, web-audio

Идея такая, при загрузке страницы сайта происходит анимация по истечению которой должен воспроизвестись определенный аудио эффект (mp3), подскажите как это можно реализовать? Частично решил вопрос следующей функцией, но при перезагрузке страницы она не срабатывает повторно

```
`setTimeout(function () {
        let audio = new Audio(); 
        audio.src = '../sounds/pencil.mp3';
        audio.autoplay = true;
    }, 2600);`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

До момента, когда должен воспроизвестись звук, т. е., в этом с лучае в течении двух с половиной секунд после загрузки страницы требуется сделать пользовательское действие на странице - клик, нажатие на клавишу или скролл. В противном случае вместо воспроизведения получим ошибку в консоли: **Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document firs - play () не удалось, потому что пользователь сначала не взаимодействовал с документом**